# nl2br and htmlentities on textarea

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, nl2br

So i have this textarea where i want people to be able to write stuff about themself and be able to use quotes around specific words and at the same time be able to make new section of text without have to write the `<br>`. I tried doing this but i failed. What am i doing wrong?

```
<textarea id="about"></textarea>

$about = nl2br($_POST["about"]);

$text = htmlentities($about, ENT_QUOTES);

$query = "INSERT INTO text VALUES('', '$text'";
$query_run = $db->query($query);
```

I inserted this into my database, but when i try to echo it out, the break doesn't apear.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM text WHERE id = '$id'";
$sql_run = $db->query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
   $about = $row["about"];
   echo $about;
}
```

example of what it looks like when i insert it.

```
cola&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;cola&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&quot;cola&quot;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;love that stuff!
```

Comment: can you put more code of the storing in the db and echoing it out?

Comment: What and how are you storing it in the DB and how are you fetching and displaying it again? This is just some random snippets.

Comment: Have you tried to do it the other way? When you select it from the database

Comment: updated with more code.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST["about"]` will be with `\n` so you don't need to use **nl2br()** with it.

Use it when you're displaying the value on a page. (e.g. `echo nl2br($about)`)

Comment: If i dont' use nl2br() the database just get pure text on my end and using nl2br afterwards wont change anything :(!

Comment: That's strange, it should work with normal textboxes.